# INSERT INTO results in a new file

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am working with hive on an external table in text format. I populate this table every hour, but I partition the table by month (The dataset is relatively small). Each hour I want to insert new data into some partitions.

The INSERT INTO clause results in the creation of a new file in the existing partition which contains the old data. This way in the end of the month i will have around 700 small files in each partition.

Is there a way for HIVE to append the data to the old file in the partition (Without using UNION ALL on the old data)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is impossible at the current time. Hopefully with the file append patch gaining more traction these days, it'll eventually be a new feature to append to the existing files.

I see this as one of the major downsides of Hive.... especially when you start dealing with much smaller inserts.